# how populate a input hidden with vuejs 2?

Tags: function, vue.js, vuejs2, populate

i want to know how pass the value that return this function to the input hidden i try with the directive v-input but doesn't work, how can i found the solution to this?.
here is the computed function:

```
  computed:{
        currentDate: function (){
        this.date = moment().format("D-MM-YYYY");
        return this.date;

    }
```

thats the view:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="customfield" class="form-control" v-model="fillProfile.customfield">
```

Comment: I don't see any code linking these two pieces together.  Where is the fillProfile object defined?

Answer (score 6):

If you expect `currentDate` to be the value of your hidden field, you should bind it like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="customfield" class="form-control" :value="currentDate">
```

`v-model` is a two-way binding, and hidden inputs are not interactive, so there is no point in using it.

Comment: ok this works populate the field, but when i want make a dd($request->all()) in laravel the debuger of laravel in the value of customfield appear me null.. thats maybe the v-model value make the send of value to controller?.

Comment: My guess is that the `dd` call is happening before the input is populated, but I don't use Laravel, so I don't know.

Comment: Can you update your question to show your request from vue to the Laravel backend?